# Netty Server throws invalid version format error

Tags: scala, playframework, netty, playframework-2.4

One of my play framework 2.4 applications in production on the EC2 console started throwing the below error though no changes were made to the server in the last 3 weeks. As you can see the error was not thrown from the app itself, but from the HttpVersion class of the Netty server. Any help in isolating the cause would be very helpful.

```
Exception caught in Netty
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: (WINDOWS NT 6.1; RV:31.0) GECKO/20100101 FIREFOX/31.0
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:94) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:62) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:75) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:191) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpMessageDecoder.decode(HttpMessageDecoder.java:102) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:500) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:554) ~[io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.channelDisconnected(FrameDecoder.java:365) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:102) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:396) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:360) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:81) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:36) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:779) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:784) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.closeRequested(SimpleChannelHandler.java:334) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleDownstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:260) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.handleDownstream(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:106) [com.typesafe.netty.netty-http-pipelining-1.1.4.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:812) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:206) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:66) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelHandler.java:156) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:130) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.exceptionCaught(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:153) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.exceptionCaught(FrameDecoder.java:377) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireExceptionCaught(Channels.java:525) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannelSink.exceptionCaught(AbstractChannelSink.java:48) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.notifyHandlerException(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:658) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:566) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [io.netty.netty-3.10.4.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

Comment: Looks like some client is indicating a malformed `HTTP-Version`. Maybe there is someone attacking your app? Maybe some client started to misbehave? See [rfc7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-2.6).